# What is the best way to define dependent variables in an object?

Tags: javascript, oop, variables, object

In the [Google developers recommendation](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-javascript) for optimizing JavaScript code, they mention that the best way to declare/initialize new variables for object is to use the prototype. For instance, instead of:

```
foo.Bar = function() {
    this.prop1_ = 4;
    this.prop2_ = true;
    this.prop3_ = [];
    this.prop4_ = 'blah';
};
```

Use:

```
foo.Bar = function() {
    this.prop3_ = [];
};

foo.Bar.prototype.prop1_ = 4;
foo.Bar.prototype.prop2_ = true;
foo.Bar.prototype.prop4_ = 'blah';
```

However, in my case I have a dependency between variables, for instance:

```
var appv2 = function(){
    this.start(this.person, this.car); 
}; 

appv2.prototype.toWhom = 'Mohamed'; 
appv2.prototype.person = new person(this.toWhom); 
appv2.prototype.car = new car();

appv2.prototype.start = function(person, car){
    console.log('start for appv2 is called'); 
    person.sayHello('me app v2');
    car.brand();    
}; 

new appv2();
```

Using `this.toWhom` outside of the main constructor body or a method function of the object will yield undefined. To solve this I could use `appv2.prototype.toWhom` instead of `this.toWhom` or I could declare my dependent variables inside of the main constructor body.

But I would like to know what is the best way, in terms of performance, to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Is your intent for those properties to be shared across all instances of your object? For example, if you create 2 `appv2` instances, the `person` and `car` references will point to the same object.

Comment: Well, I have a large application in hand and some of my use cases will require me to share the default variables among all objects in order to improve the performance, and I am asking on how to do that for dependent variables!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reference `toWhom` while creating `person`, you can either store the value in a separate variable:

```
var toWhom = appv2.prototype.toWhom = 'Mohamed';
appv2.prototype.person = new person(toWhom);
```

Or, reference it from the `prototype`, as you suspected:

```
appv2.prototype.person = new person(appv2.prototype.toWhom);
```

The reason `this.toWhom` is `undefined` is because `this` doesn't refer to an instance of `appv2` there.

Comment: thanks for replying, It is possible to reference from the prototype and it is possible to use a variable to hold the value (something I don't want to do), but i am looking for an answer on which way is the best to accomplish this in terms of performance in general? and yes I am aware that altering the value for the object would alter it for all instances!

Comment: @MohamedAliJamaoui The performance difference between the 2 options I listed will be negligible. That code should only be evaluated once, so it's not going to give you a great gain in trying to speed it up much more. For the rest, Google is right in saying to prefer the `prototype`, but to prefer it when it makes sense. Yeah, setting shared values anew for each instance can be a waste, but trying to set unique values on the `prototype` isn't going to work out very well -- regardless of the supposed performance gains.